# Why doesn't the problem of determining whether a word has the same number of 0's and 1's prove $P \neq L$?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time

One big problem in complexity theory is $P$ vs $L$. I was just thinking about why this isn't trivial, and I came up with the following example. Of course, it cannot work as a proof as it seems too easy. So what is wrong in the below "proof?"

Let $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$. $L \subset \Sigma^*$ where

$$
l \in L \iff \text{the number of zeros is equal to the number of ones}
$$

This language can be decided in polynomial, even linear, time. We can just loop through the input and count the number of zeros and ones.

But this language cannot be determined in logarithmic time.

Proof:

Consider the input $\{0\}^N + \{1\}^N \in L$ and call this input $a$.

Now suppose we have an input $b = \{0\}^{N-1} + \{1\}^{N+1} \notin L$.

The only way for this algorithm to differentiate between $a$ and $b$ is by looking at the $(N-1)$th index of the input, which requires $O(N)$ steps. This is not logarithmic, thus $P \neq L$.

What is the error here?

Comment: L is defined as log-space, not log-time.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov That'll do it then. Haha